# Should the "set" method(s) of a class return "void" or "boolean"?

Tags: java, class, validation, oop, constructor

So I run into this fairly often when I'm designing a class:

```
class foo {

    private Bar bar;

    public foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

So far, so good, right?  But then I think "How do I know that the user will pass an acceptable `bar` object?  So then:

```
    private bool validateBar(Bar bar) {
        return amIgood(bar);
    }
```

Well, of course I need to put this with the `setBar` function like so:

```
    public bool setBar(Bar bar) {
        if (validateBar(bar)) {
            this.bar = bar;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Well, if that's what I need to do, then I have to include in the constructor, too, right?  Except that the constructor does not have an option to return anything other than a `foo` object, so I try and think of workarounds, like this:

```
    public foo(Bar bar) {
        if validateBar(bar)
            this.bar = bar;
        else
            throw Exception("Invalid bar passed along to foo");
    }
```

Or:

```
    public foo(Bar bar) {
        if (!setBar(bar))
            throw Exception("Invalid bar passed along to foo");
    }
```

You can see how something simple went out of control pretty quickly.  It's even worse if there's some sort of sanitation to do on top of the validation.

So my question is how to approach the problem of validation while keeping a class structure relatively simple?

**Edit**
The first example for `setbar` was supposed to be `void` but accidentally put `bar`, now corrected

Comment: "*Should the “set” method(s) of a class return “void” or “boolean”?*" - They should return `this`! `</opinion>` If the parameter is illegal, why not throw an `IllegalArgumentException`? If there is some logic to the setter, i.e. some validation has to be done, then it should not be a setter, rather a `validateAndSet...(...)` (or equivalent).

Comment: @Turing85 I strongly disagree with your `validateAndSet...(...)` idea. What's the point of setters if you can't add validation to them?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon depepnds on the "heavyness" of the validation. If it's something simple (e.g. null checks), a setter is justified. If it is more complex, then I would suggest not palcing it in the setter.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I agree in general programming, but more often than not you just have to provide a setter of your using frameworks like Jackson, mapstruct, JPA etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of the above.

Conventionally, setters return `void`, but may return the type of the instance (in this case `Foo`, not `Bar`) if implementing a [*fluent interface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), in which case the setter method’s last line is `return this;`. (Your example is missing a return and thus does not compile).

If the parameter to a setter must be “valid”, that should not affect the return type. Rather, the method should explode:

```
public void setBar(Bar bar) {
    if (!validateBar(bar)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bar is invalid");
    }
    this.bar = bar;
}
```

A good reason not to return boolean here is that the caller may not check the return and may blindly continue as if everything is OK, which of course would be bad.

Further, it is better to make it impossible to create an invalid `Bar` by moving the logic of `validateBar()` inside the `Bar` constructor, throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` if the parameters passed in would create an invalid `Bar`, then you could remove the check from `Foo`.

If the `validateBar()` method is `static` it means the a `Bar` can be validated without the context of a `Foo`, so the logic should be implemented in `Bar` -  `Foo` should not have the responsibility or knowledge of how to validate a `Bar` if it doesn't need to.

However, if `Foo` has special requirements for a valid `Bar` that doesn't apply elsewhere, create a subclass of `Bar`, eg `FooBar extends Bar`, that implements `Foo`'s special validation requirements, again in its constructor.

If validating a `Bar` *does* need the context of a `Foo` to validate, and reusing `Bar` instances between `Foo`s is *not* required, then the `Bar` class should be an *inner* class of `Foo`, in which case the validation can still be in the Bar`constructor, and the state of the containing`Foo` is available to the validation logic as required.

If validating a `Bar` needs the context of a `Foo` to validate, *and* reusing `Bar` instances *is* required, then `Bar` cannot be an inner class and the validation code should live in `Foo` as you have suggested with your `validateBar(Bar bar)` method, except it wouldn't be `static` so the method would have the fields of `Foo` to use.

Also, consider re-naming it `validate(Bar bar)`, since the type of the parameter makes it clear what is being validated.

Comment: Thanks, this answer makes sense to me.  Would it be good form for the class to have a static validation function for use before initiating the class?  Also, the lack of a return was a mistake, it was supposed to be void, now corrected.

Comment: @spiff I've added a bit more content to my answer. Let me know if that doesn't answer your questions.

Comment: that is to say the "chained" methods. If this answer was not here I would have written myself +1